# Custom taxonomy query broken after upgrade to 4.4

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, template-hierarchy

I just upgraded from 4.2 to 4.4 and now my taxonomy query returns empty. It has been working fine prior to the upgrade.

I have registered a custom taxonomy named `'title'`, which is used by my custom post type `'sg-publications'`. Following the WP template hierarchy I created a template called `taxonomy-title.php` which uses the default query args, and up until now has correctly shown each publication by it's title.

Here is the output of $queried_object and $wp_query->request in that template:

```
[queried_object] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 1256
        [name] => Stroupe Scoop
        [slug] => stroupe-scoop
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 1374
        [taxonomy] => title
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 30
        [filter] => raw
    )

[queried_object_id] => 1256

[request] => 
SELECT wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_title = 'stroupe-scoop' 
AND ( 
    wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
    IN (1374)
    ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'sg-publications' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'
    ) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date 
DESC
```

The problem I see in the above query is right after `WHERE 1=1`, for some reason it is searching for `post_title = 'stroupe-scoop'`. This is not correct - that is the taxonomy term slug, not the title of the post. In fact, when I comment out that line and run it against the database I get the proper returns. So what is causing WP to add that condition, when (I assume) it was not adding it before I upgraded to 4.4?

Here is taxonomy-title.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Chocolate
 */
  global $wp_query;

  $quer_object = get_queried_object();
  $tax_desc    = $quer_object->description;
  $tax_name    = $quer_object->name;
  $tax_slug    = $quer_object->slug;

get_header();
get_sidebar();

$title = get_the_title( $ID );
$args  = array(
    'menu'            => 'new-publications',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_id'    => $tax_slug . '-menu',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu-top-style nav nav-tab',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => false,
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-fw fa-2x"></i>',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

?>

<div id="page-title">
  <h1><?php _e( 'Publications - ' . $tax_name, LANGUAGE_ZONE ); ?></h1>
  <p><?php _e( 'View our monthly newsletter and stay informed on the latest real estate news.', LANGUAGE_ZONE ); ?></p>

<?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>

</div>

<div id="multicol">

<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

get_template_part( 'loop' , 'title' );

endwhile;
endif;
?>

</div><!-- end #multicol -->
<section class="page-text well"><?php _e( $tax_desc, LANGUAGE_ZONE ); ?></section>

<?php
get_footer();
```

And in functions.php I have this query filter:

```
// use pre_get_posts to remove pagination from publications
function gd_publications_pagination( $query ) {
  if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
    return;

  if ( is_tax('title') ) {
    // Display all posts for the taxonomy called 'title'
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
    return;
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'gd_publications_pagination', 1 );
```

Comment: Where is the query code? If it's in your template then why don't you just remove the part that's breaking it? If it's not - what did you use to generate the query?

Comment: There is no custom query code, I'm using the WP default loop. Because I'm following the Template Hierarchy, WP should (and has, prior to upgrade) generate the correct query parameters for my taxonomy.

Comment: What's the contents of your `taxonomy-title.php`? Did you look in theme's `functions.php` to check if there are any filters on the main query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using a taxonomy slug that coincides with the public query variables, like `title`.

The `title`  query variable was introduced in 4.4 so I think that could explain your problems.

Check out [this part](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/dc31b503ece422127a47ca7d4a81d9f3b8b73222/wp-includes/query.php#L1483) of the `WP_Query` class:

```
    if ( '' !== $q['title'] ) {
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare( 
            " AND $wpdb->posts.post_title = %s", 
            stripslashes( $q['title'] ) 
        );
    }
```

So when we use for example:

```
example.tld/?title=test
```

what should WordPress do here? Is it a taxonomy query or title search?

So I would recommend **prefixing** the custom taxonomy slug, e.g.

```
gary_title
```

to avoid possible name collisions.

### Update:

Thanks to @ocean90 for [pointing out](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212532/custom-taxonomy-query-broken-after-upgrade-to-4-4/212537?noredirect=1#comment309043_212537) that this is a bug, that will be [fixed](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35115) in 4.4.1

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the change in 4.4 - I had a suspicion it might be a naming conflict. I'll follow once I run a few tests.

Comment: Until a few versions ago, you couldn't register a post type `code`, because that made the whole admin backend monospaced. Generic names are always collision candidates. On the other hand, WordPress should prefix its own internals.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Once I changed the taxonomy term and related filenames to a non-conflicting scheme, all came back up. Thanks again for pointing me at the updated WP code.

Comment: glad to hear it's up & running again @GaryD

Comment: cool, I've to test that when I get my hands on an old install ;-)  I would definitely support that prefix ticket, but I don't see that going through  in the near future, sadly  @toscho

Comment: In 4.4.1 `title` will be removed from the public query vars list, see ticket [#35115](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35115).